# Void Factorial Using Pointers in C

Tags: c

I want to do a void factorial function in C that uses pointers. This is my code but it won't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void factorial(int, int*);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int r = 0;

    printf("Enter n : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("No factorial for negative");
    }
    else
    {
        factorial(n , &r);
        printf("factorial of %d is %d", n, r);
    }
}

void factorial(int n , int *r)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        *r= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *r= n* factorial((n-1), r);
    }
}
```

The error I get is in the last line of the code saying : invalid operands of type "int" and "void" to binary operator * , what does that mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Right, your `factorial` function doesn't return a value, but your tail call to `factorial` is treating it like it does.

Comment: It means you're trying to use the return value of a function that doesn't return a value.

Comment: you are using it recursively, but it doesn't return a value

Comment: As a warning, do not delete the contents of your question again. People took the time to help you, and it's disrespectful to them to deface your question afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `factorial()` returns `void`.

Try:

```
factorial((num-1), result);
*result= num *(*result);
```

Instead of that line.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if factorial() returns void (which is basically , returning nothing) , this line does not make any sense

```
*result = num * factorial ((num-1), result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use return value of a function if it is declared to return void.
If you want to declare function this way then your factorial function can be:

```
  void factorial(int num , int *result)
  {
  if (num == 0 || num == 1)
  {
    //*result = 1;
    return;
  }
  else
  {
      *result *= num;
      factorial ((num-1), result);
  }
```

But also in `main` function you should change `int res = 0` into `int res = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Factorial(int *a,int *result){
if (*a == 0 || *a == 1){
    return;
}
else{
    *result *= *a;
    *a -= 1;
    Factorial(a,result);
}}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?